# How to navigate up in c++ files using relative paths

Tags: c++

I'm using files for making operations on a txt file shared between 2 projects.
A grand folder contains both projects files and I want to use something like this`system("..\ theOtherProject/launchEXEFromOtherProject.exe")` to launch an "exe" from the other project.

The problem is I can't navigate up to the grand folder to choose the other project folder

It has to be relative path since I'm sending this to another person and fixed path will not work. Any help please?

Comment: Why is there a tab in the path? Is there really a directory named `..<tab>theOtherProject` ? (`<tab>` just indicates the position of the tab char)

Comment: Your question is totally unrelated to c++. It is a question which parameter a library functions takes and what the library function will do with it. If the library function is able to handle relative path descriptions, everything works fine. If not, prepare a absolute path before. Helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Comment: @Klaus isn't ```system()``` a built in function in c++ not an external library? All I need to do is just launch a file. nothing too complicated.

Comment: system() is part of an external library and you must link to it to access it.  As all from stdlib.h is typically automatically linked, you may have not noticed, that this is a external library.

Comment: @fabian I meant that first "..\" go up in directory, then space, then select another folder inside the main directory we just reached by "../"
This is actually not a functional code, I'm just looking for something to work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate up, e.g. this works fine on my Windows 10 PC:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    system(R"(..\..\..\..\..\Windows\notepad.exe)");
}
```

Here a raw string is used. Then you can also use the Windows path separators, if you like.

Instead of the raw string you can also escape the slashes, like:

```
system("..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Windows\\notepad.exe")
```

When you wish a more portable solution, you may consider using std::filesystem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path;
    path = path / ".." / ".." / ".." / ".." / ".." / "Windows" / "notepad.exe";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << path; // path is now quoted. So that spaces in the path are handled appropriately.
    system(ss.str().c_str());
}
```